# GCC does not support brace elision in a new-expression

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, list-initialization, aggregate-initialization, brace-elision

Consider this program:

```cpp
struct S {
    int m;
};

int main() {
    S s_arr[1]{0};
    S *s_new = new S[1]{0};
    int i_arr[1][1]{0};
    int (*i_new)[1] = new int[1][1]{0};
    return 0;
}
```

I think all four variables in the main function should be initialized using aggregate initialization.

However, GCC only accepts `s_arr` and `i_arr`, but rejects `s_new` and `i_new`, reporting (g++ 8.3.0 on Ubuntu):

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:7:26: error: could not convert ‘0’ from ‘int’ to ‘S’
     S *s_new = new S[1]{0};
                          ^
test.cpp:9:38: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
     int (*i_new)[1] = new int[1][1]{0};
                                      ^
test.cpp:9:38: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

(note: the last duplicate line is produced by g++)

I also tested on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/p7xbV3), none of the gcc versions from 6.1 to 9.2 can compile this program. 6.x and 7.x versions also give the message saying: "*sorry, unimplemented: cannot initialize multi-dimensional array with initializer*" for `i_new`.

Changing `{0}` to `{{0}}` resolves both `s_new` and `inew` for all GCC versions tested on godbolt (6.1 to 9.2). I can understand this, as both `S[1]` and `int[1][1]` are both aggregate types whose element type is a sub-aggregate (array of `S`; array of array). However, C++ allows these braces to be elided, and GCC accepts `s_arr` and `i_arr`, where these braces are elided.

In the other hand, clang 6.0.0 to clang 9.0.0 accepts the original program happily.

In the specification of C++14 (gnu++14 is the default for GCC 6.5/7.4/8.3/9.2),

> 5.3.4 New / 17
>
> A new-expression that creates an object of type T initializes that object as follows:
>
> ......
>
> (17.2) — Otherwise, the new-initializer is interpreted according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for direct initialization.

The new-initializer should be interpreted as direct-initialization. As `s_arr` and `i_arr` are also direct-initialized, I think they should be interpreted in the same way, and the original program should be well-formed.

Is there anything that I am missing here, or is this a bug in GCC?

I tried to search through GCC Bugzilla, but didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: `{0}` is often misleading, as it means "zero-initialize the first element and value-initialize the rest". It's better to just use `{}` or `()` to value-initialize the entire object (this will set it to 0). Incidentally that also compiles fine on gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely a bug.  `new` expressions are defined to use the rules for direct-initialization ([[expr.new]/18.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#18.2)), and brace elision applies to all cases of aggregate initialization ([[dcl.init.aggr]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.aggr#12)).

File a bug if you can't find one after searching through the bugzilla.